# Closing a Parent Window after Modal is closed in JQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I am trying to close the Parent Window when a Modal Window is Closed.
I created a custom Modal Window using JQuery UI and i am not able to close the parent window.

```
$(document).ready(function () {           
        dialog = $("#dialog").dialog({
            autoOpen: false,
            height: 300,
            width: 500,
            modal: true,
            buttons: {
                "Approve": addUser,
                Cancel: function () {
                    dialog.dialog("close");
                }
            }
        }); 

        });

 function addUser() {

          var getJSON = function (url) {
                return new Promise(function (resolve, reject) {
                    var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
                    xhr.open('get', url, true);
                    xhr.withCredentials = true;
                    xhr.onload = function () {
                        var status = xhr.status;
                        if (status == 200) {
                            resolve(xhr.response);
                        } else {
                            reject(status);
                        }
                    };
                    xhr.send();
                });
            };

            getJSON(url).then(function (data) {
                var result = "Approved Successfully"
                dialog.dialog("close");                    
                alert(result);
                window.close(); ///Here, the PARENT Window is not closing

            }, function (status) { //error detection....
                alert('Something went wrong.');
            });
}
```

Here, my Modal Box is closing but **window.close()** is not closing the parent window.

I am getting an Message **"Scripts may close only the windows that were opened by it."**

How to solve this issue.

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Create function in parent window

```
window.parent.close();
```